# Compare two columns and replace the value in column 2 with NA if same as column 1

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements, data-cleaning

I have a data frame with 4 columns and I want to compare val1 and val2 and if the numerical values are the same then replace val2 with "NA".Notice row3 of the dataframe has 123 in val1 and 1236 in val2 so these are not the same and thus should be left as such.

```
actual data:
structure(list(record_id = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), name = c("CDK19", 
"DYNC1H1", "G6PD", "NPRL2", "CHD2", "LGI1"), val1 = c("c.386A>C", 
"c.G5864T", "c.T1058C", "c.323_339+19del", "c.2876+3_2876+6delAAGT", 
"c.757G>A"), val2 = c(NA, "c.5864G>T", NA, "c.323_339+19del", 
"c.2876+3_2876+6delAAGT", "c.757G>A")), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

dummy data:

```
# rec_id    name    val1    val2
# 1 abby    g.B123C g.123B>C
# 1 Amy     g.B183C g.123B>C
# 2 abby    g.B123C g.1236B>C
# 3 Amy     g.2876+3_2876+6delABC   g.2876+3_2876+6delABC
# 4 Amber   g.2876+3_2876+6delABC   g.2876+3_2876+6delABC
# 5 Axe     g.2876G>C   NA
```

Desired output

```
# rec_id    name    val1    val2
# 1 abby    g.B123C NA
# 1 Amy g.B183C g.123B>C
# 2 abby    g.B123C g.1236B>C
# 3 Amy g.2876+3_2876+6delABC   NA
# 4 Amber   g.2876+3_2876+6delABC   NA
# 5 Axe g.2876+g>c  NA
```

My code:

```r
mydata %>%
  for (i in 1:nrow(mydata)) {
    if (mydata$val1[i] == mydata$val2[i]) {
      mydata$val2[i] <- NA
    }
  }
```

Update: more data:

```
df2 <- structure(list(record_id = c(125L, 125L), name = c("ADAMTS17", "ARHGEF10"), val1 = c("arr.GRCh37.15q26.1q26.3_92401782_102383473_x3dn", "arr.GRCh37.8p23.3p23.2_191530_3846288_x1dn"), val2 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
df3 <- structure(list(record_id = 586:591, name = c("COQ4", "COQ4", "TTC7A", "COL11A1", "GJB2", "LNX1"), val1 = c("c.190C>T", "c.190C>T", "c.1433T>C", "c.4325T>C", "c.109G>A", "c.1662A>C"), val2 = c("c.197_198delGCinsAA", "c.197_198delGCinsAA", "c.1288-1G>T", NA, NA, "c.680C>T")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Do you want to replace matching character strings with the character string `"NA"` or with the missing value `NA`?  In either case, you should use a vectorised `ifelse` function rather than an `if ... else` statement.

Comment: Missing value NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
library(stringr)

mutate(df3, val2 = if_else(as.character(str_extract_all(val1, "\\d+")) == as.character(str_extract_all(val2, "\\d+")), 
                           NA_character_, val2))
```

We extract the numbers using [stringr](/questions/tagged/stringr), turn the lists into character vectors, then compare.

Data:

```
mydata <- structure(list(rec_id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), name = c("abby", 
"Amy", "abby", "Amy", "Amber", "Axe"), val1 = c("g.B123C", "g.B183C", 
"g.B123C", "g.2876+3_2876+6delABC", "g.2876+3_2876+6delABC", 
"g.2876G>C"), val2 = c("g.123B>C", "g.123B>C", "g.1236B>C", "g.2876+3_2876+6delABC", 
"g.2876+3_2876+6delABC", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Error in `mutate_cols()`:
! Problem with `mutate()` column `val2`.
ℹ `val2 = if_else(...)`.
✖ non-conformable arrays

Comment: @akang can you run dput on mydata, and add it to your question?

Comment: @akang yeah it works for me - all numbers are replaced because the numbers in both columns are the same

Comment: Yeah, it works on the head for me as well but not the entire data frame.

Comment: in that case, you might want to include a different example (a longer one, or maybe filtering for the rows that cause you trouble)

Comment: structure(list(record_id = c(125L, 125L), name = c("ADAMTS17", 
"ARHGEF10"), val1 = c("arr.GRCh37.15q26.1q26.3_92401782_102383473_x3dn", 
"arr.GRCh37.8p23.3p23.2_191530_3846288_x1dn"), val2 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: @akang thanks for that! there were a couple of bugs in the code

Comment: structure(list(record_id = 586:591, name = c("COQ4", "COQ4", 
"TTC7A", "COL11A1", "GJB2", "LNX1"), val1 = c("c.190C>T", "c.190C>T", 
"c.1433T>C", "c.4325T>C", "c.109G>A", "c.1662A>C"), val2 = c("c.197_198delGCinsAA", 
"c.197_198delGCinsAA", "c.1288-1G>T", NA, NA, "c.680C>T")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) # This would give me an error as well

Comment: I missed a thing! Should work now